# How can I solve the issue with redirection?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am setting up a new project on nuxt and I've made one new layout for a login page, and created a page `login`.
In my `default` layout I am setting `middleware: 'auth'` and in my middleware I am checking for a token and if not authenticated I am redirecting the user to the login page.

The funny thing is that when I've just set it up it worked fine but after some time (I tried to go back with my code to find the issue) I started to receive an Error `Redirected when going from "/" to "/login" via a navigation guard.`

I don't have any redirects but the one in the `auth` middleware.

What can be a problem here that I cannot see?

```
// middleware/auth.js

export default ({ app, error, redirect }) => {
    const hasToken = !!app.$apolloHelpers.getToken()
    if (!hasToken) {
        error({
            errorCode: 503,
            message: 'You are not allowed to see this'
        })
        return redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

```
// layouts/default.vue

<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>

    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar :clipped-left="clipped" fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
 
      <v-btn icon @click.stop="clipped = !clipped">
        <v-icon>mdi-application</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
 
      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" />
      <v-spacer />
 
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

    <v-footer :absolute="!fixed" app>
      <span>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: ['auth'],
  data() {
    return {
      clipped: false,
      drawer: true,
      fixed: true,
      items: [
        {
          icon: 'mdi-apps',
          title: 'Welcome',
          to: '/',
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline',
          title: 'Clients',
          to: '/clients',
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-briefcase-check-outline',
          title: 'Orders',
          to: '/orders',
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-briefcase-clock-outline',
          title: 'Pending Orders',
          to: '/pending-orders',
        },
      ],
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
      title: 'Title',
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

```
// layouts/login.vue

<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default { }
</script>
```

```
// pages/login.vue

<template>
  <div>test login</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry) apparently I removed `layout` property from the login page component

Comment: So does the issue still occur or did you solve it? :)

Comment: @Braks sorry man, I apparently removed layout property from the login page) I guess a bit tired but thanks for checking on this ;)